# How can one show that if $a$ divides $b$ where $a$ and $b$ are Gaussian integers, then conjugate of $a$ divides conjugate of $b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can one show that if $a$ divides $b$ where $a$ and $b$ are Gaussian integers, then conjugate of $a$ divides conjugate of $b$

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Conjugation is a homomorphism of rings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a=s+it$ and $b=u+iv$. If $(x+iy)(s+it)=u+iv$ then $(x-iy)(s-it)=u-iv$.  The product of the conjugates is the conjugate of the product.